# Application of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, invariant-subspace

By definition, a bounded linear operator $T: X \to X$ has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace W on a Banach space $X$ if for every vector $\omega \in W$, $T(\omega)$ belongs to $W$ (i.e, $T(W) \subset W$).

Could anyone help me with an example of applications of an operator that has a nontrivial closed invariant subspace?

Comment: I assume here you want an infinite-dimensional invariant subspace? Otherwise the classic example is an operator that has eigenvalues.

Comment: I this case, we are assuming that the operator has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace either in the finite or infinite-dimensional space. Then, what is an application of such an operator in a practical way?

Comment: A classic example would be the spectra of certain operators in quantum mechanics being associated to values of certain physical quantities; thus having point spectra (and thus eigenspaces) naturally connects with quantization. But the examples are endless and it seems difficult to provide good examples without knowing what you're looking for, or what your background is.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am working on the Invariant Subspace Problem

Comment: For the invariant subspace problem, most of the "difficult" linear operators don't have "nice" proper invariant subspaces, right? So I guess invariant subspaces that are either eigenspaces or that arise from shift operators (generalized eigenspaces) aren't so interesting in that context...